# How do I export Photoshop Raws with PC byte order? (Photoshop CC 2015)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, raw-format

I know that older versions of Adobe Photoshop allowed you to choose Mac/IBM PC byte order when saving as a Photoshop RAW, but the option's not visible in CC 2015.1.

Comment: Why do you want to?. 

Also, you can't "save as raw". You can save as other formats; jpg, tiff, png, gif, etc. Did you mean one of those?

Comment: "Photoshop Raw," or `.raw` is the filetype. Yes, I'm absolutely sure it exits– it's necessary to create heightmaps for video games.

Comment: Raw is the original file format. You can't "save as raw" but you can save a raw file to the formats I mentioned earlier. I think the "Mac/PC byte order" shows up when you are saving as a tiff. But I've never seen that to make any difference, whether I'm using a PC or a Mac.

Comment: Note that this option only appears when the document is 16-bit